# Use try-with-resources or close this "Stream" in a "finally" clause

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sonarqube

I am having trouble to apply the suggested method by Sonarqube scan in this line of code/method.

Sonarqube says, **"Use try-with-resources or close this "Stream" in a "finally" clause."**

```
Files.list(voucherDirectory)
```

```
    @Override
    public String getLastModifiedFile() {
        Path voucherDirectory = Paths.get(vouchiDir);
        Optional<Path> lastFilePath = Optional.empty();
        try {
            lastFilePath = Files.list(voucherDirectory)
                    .filter(f -> !Files.isDirectory(f))
                    .max(Comparator.comparingLong(f -> f.toFile()
                            .lastModified()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        if (lastFilePath.isPresent()) {
            return lastFilePath.get().getFileName().toString();
        }
        return "none";
    }
```

Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
        try (Stream<Path> list = Files.list(voucherDirectory)) {
            lastFilePath = list
                    .filter(f -> !Files.isDirectory(f))
                    .max(Comparator.comparingLong(f -> f.toFile()
                            .lastModified()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
```

Comment: If I'm getting it right replacing the try block with this code should do the trick, right? 

Comment: Yes. Just replace your `try` with this one.